# Case statement in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an AuditLog with things like id, action, type, description...

What I'd like to do in the view is something like:

```
case description
  when "created"
    <li>created styling</li>
  when "deleted"
    <li>deleted styling</li>
  else
    <li>error</li>
end
```

Trying to learn how to do this in a view and the correct syntax, which the resources I found on Google don't specify.

Comment: [Check this out.](http://techspry.com/ruby_and_rails/how-to-write-case-statement-into-views-rails-quick-tips/)
I found the solution in this blog! Hope I helped :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your styling contains lots of tags and HTML elements, I would suggest putting them into partials:

```
<%= render :partial => @audit_log.description rescue nil %>
```

If you `description` is `created`, then it would render the file `_created.html.erb` in the same folder as the current view

If it is `deleted`, render `_deleted.html.erb` automatically.

If `description` is something else, which has no `_something.html.erb` file, then nothing would be displayed (without `rescue nil`, error will occurs)

======

If you want to render the partial in some different folder,

```
<%= render :partial => "some/where/#{@audit_log.description}" %>
```

Comment: that seems like a nice clean approach. TWhat I can't wrap my head around is my database fields are ID, ACTION, TYPE, DESCRIPTION, DATA... And Data should hold a Has associated data based on the type... So I want the CASE statement to detect the TYPE, and then output the info. the info is different for every TYPE, which is why I'm using a DATA field full of meta data.... So I would need to use a CAST to detect the type, then send it to a partial like _auditlogItem.html.erb.... Perhaps in the partial, I can pass the string based on the ACTION type like "James Bond deleted the Book_id. Thoughts?

Comment: actually I am quite confused by your database fields...What's exactly the natures are the ACTION, TYPE and DESCRIPTION? So you would determine the TYPE first, in order to fetch the DATA correctly. Then `deleted`, `created` is the ACTION or the DESCRIPTION?

Comment: Example: 1 | CREATED | PHOTO | DATA .... And Data would be a HASH (i think that's the way to go, but IDK yet) DATA would be created with an observer {photo_name: "asdadasd", photo_id: "3131"} the idea with this is to be able to output without requiring joins across multiple tables. Thoughts?

Comment: DESCRIPTION's not here. So for each pair of TYPE and ACTION, create a partial for it naming "#{TYPE}_#{ACTION}" (ie. _photo_created.html.erb) is OK? They would be very similar or quite different? Too much uncertainty and I can't guess anymore...

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<%= 
  case @audit_log.description
  when "created" then "created styling"
  when "deleted" then "deleted styling"
  else "error"
  end
%>
```

Comment: Thanks,, one issue... I want it to be HTML for the WHEN.... so when "created" <li>lots of stuff</li>.. but it errors with HTML.. how do I make Rails accept an HTML block of code when the case is satisfied?

Comment: Maybe wrap that tag up in `<li><%= case ... %></li>`.  What error are you seeing?  (Personally, I prefer using `<% if %>` statements in views for readability.)

Answer (score -2):

actually it would be better and easier to use Jquery's addclass function